# Is it the optimal way of expressing "go through all nodes" queries in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a quite large social graph in which I execute global queries like this one:

```
match (n:User)-[r:LIKES]->(k:User)
where not (k:User)-[]->(n:User)
return count(r);
```

They take a lot of time and memory, so I am curious if they are expressed in optimal way. I have felling that when I execute such query Cypher is firstly matching everything that fits the expression (and that takes a lot of memory) and then starts to count things. I would rather like to go through every node, check the pattern and update the counter if necessary. This way such queries would not require a lot of memory. So how in fact such query is executed? If it is not optimal, is there a way to make it better (in Cypher)?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the query just as you wrote it, you may not be getting what you think you are. Putting labels on node "variables" can cause them to be treated as fresh (partial) patterns instead of bound nodes. Is your query any faster if you use

```
MATCH (n:User)-[r:LIKES]->(k:User)
WHERE NOT (n)<--(k)
RETURN count(r)
```

Here's how this works (not considering internal optimizations, which I don't begin to understand).

For each User node, every outgoing LIKES relationship is followed. If the other end of the LIKES relationship is a User node, the two nodes and the relationship are bound to the names n, k, and r and passed to the WHERE clause. Every outgoing relationship on the bound k node is then tested to see if it connects to the bound n node. If no such relationship is found, the match is considered successful. The count() function in the RETURN clause counts the resulting collection of relationships that were passed from the match.

If you have a densely connected graph, and particularly if there are many other relationships between nodes other than LIKES relationship, this can be quite an extensive search.

As a further experiment, you might try changing the WHERE clause to read

```
WHERE NOT (k)-->(n)
```

and see if it makes any difference. I don't think it will, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It seems that you are right. It is faster: 1692689 ms vs 951958 ms. However, I am still not sure if it is the most optimal way.